# UUID for iBeacon for LE advertisement

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I want to develop an App in Android 6. I need to transmit iBeacon packet.

As I checked in iBeacon advertisement packet spec we need to transmit UUID along with major number and minor number.

So my question is this

Is there any process/License for generation UUID ?

Comment: Nope. Just generate any uuid you like.

Comment: Thanks for response. After UUID generation is there any step to register the UUID on on Apple site?

Comment: nope.  Assuming you have used the `uuidgen` command line on macOS or something similar to generated the UUID the chances of a collision with some other uuid are infinitesimally small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use any byte sequence you want for a ProximityUUID, they are designed to be universally unique so you can be confident that your byte sequence is not used by others.  If this is your goal, you will want to use a dedicated UUID generator, which uses a secure random number generator and a seed value to generate a byte sequence that has a very high probability of being globally unique.

Android has a built in API to do this here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html

There are also plenty of online web-based tools that do the same.  A quick Google search for "UUID generator" will find several options.

Comment: Thanks for response . I refereed many sites and its mentioned that UUID can be generated through https://www.uuidgenerator.net. If I generate a new UUID whether it is guaranteed to be unique ? Is there any step to register our UUID on on Apple site?

Comment: Thanks for response . I refereed many sites and its mentioned that UUID can be generated through uuidgenerator.net. 
After UUID is generated is there any step to register the UUID on on Apple site?

Comment: No need to register the UUID with Apple.  The beauty of a "universally unique identifier" is that mathematics makes it unique.  There is no need for a central authority.